# FCM iOS send push notification to a topic to killed app

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an iOS app that uses FCM to do push notifications. In the app I subscribe to FCM topic. While app is running in the in the background, I am able to send and receive push notifications:

```
{
    "to": "/topics/mytopic",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Title",
        "body": "Body"
    },
    "content_available": true
}
```

If I kill the application, push notifications are not delivered. However, I am still able to receive push notifications that are sent from the Firebase Console using "User segment".

Is there a way to send push notifications to a topic when iOS app is killed?

Comment: When you push the message from the console is it just displayed as a notification on the device?

Comment: @Paulw11, yes, it displayed as onscreen notification

Comment: When your app is killed, push notifications can't be delivered to it. If you send a `content-available` push without any other content while the app terminated then iOS just discards it. If it contains a title/body as in your question then iOS displays that to the user, but the notification is only delivered to your app if the user taps on it, so the short answer is you can't deliver a push to a terminated app (user swiped up)

Comment: @Paulw11, do I correctly understand that I have to add "data" attribute then with some other content inside?
And also, I am not interested if the notification is *delivered* to the app or something. I am only interested that the push notification I send is shown on the screen for the user.

Comment: If the data you send doesn't contain the `notification` dictionary then there is nothing for iOS to display, so nothing is displayed.

Comment: @Paulw11, I understand that. I am sending what I have stated in the question. My previous comment was about if I should add a "data" attribute, fx `{ "to": ..., "notification": { ... }, "data": { } }`

Comment: According to the documentation, the `data` with no `notificstion` results in a silent push. Adding the `notification` should give a message even if the app is terminated

Comment: Try using priority high, when sending messages. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json

Comment: please can you tell me how to send it using php in topics?